# Mapper Failing with Heap space issue

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, mapreduce, emr

I have written a custom Map Reduce code to simulate the FlatMap behavior i.e. the input to mapper is a S3 location which contains Tuple of {Key, collection}. The mapper only iterates over the data and returns the collection.
The input to mapper is 27 files in S3 having size 238 MB each. When the map/reduce code runs the split decided is 57. The number of reducer for the job is 0.

Mapper Code:

```
    @Override
protected void map(final LongWritable key, @Nonnull final Text value, @Nonnull final Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(value);
    Objects.requireNonNull(context);

    T input;
    try {
        input = mapper.readValue(value.toString(), componentFunction.getInputClass());
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        throw new CafeMapReduceException("Failed to deserialize input: " + value.toString(), e);
    }
    PartitionerFlatmapComponentOutput output = new PartitionerFlatmapComponentOutput().setNotifications(input.getNotificationTuple().getValue());
    writeToContext(context, output);
}

    protected void writeToContext(@Nonnull final Context context, @Nonnull final U output)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (output instanceof Collection) {
        for (Object element : (Collection) output) {
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(mapper.writeValueAsString(element)));
        }
    } else {
        throw new CafeMapReduceException("Invalid output for flatMap. Output type: " + output.getClass());
    }
}
```

I tried to run this code with following configuration:
mapreduce.map.java.opts = -Xmx4096m
But, it fails with Java Heap Space issue. I even tried with multiple GC algorithm like -XX:+UseParallelGC, concurrentGC but it still fails with same error.

Mappers completes successfully when we provide heap space of 10 GB to mapper.

I am not able to figure out why the mapper needs 10 GB of memory. I am using Hadoop 2.7.3. Any help in what way we should proceed to resolve this issue will be helpful.

... Adding More Details...

The each 250 MB which is sent to mapper has only 1 line i.e. JSON representation of Tuple{Key, Collection}. I got the heap dump and ran analyzer, it shows following things:

The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0x6c018b708 main keeps local variables with total size 3,030,076,656 (98.29%) bytes.
[image]

I am getting why this much of memory is retained by local variables.

Comment: also set mapreduce.map.memory.mb to value ~ 1.2 * mapreduce.map.java.opts

Comment: We have set mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 5120m but still it fails with same issue